# Custom categorization of tweets using NLTK - Python

Tags: python, twitter, categories, bigdata, nltk

I have loads of tweets in my database; I need to categorize the tweets under different categories just by tagging not saving in different list  i i did write some code to work -- but it will inefficient for big data because of **for** loop

```
category_dict = {}
    category_dict['agronomy']  = ['cropping','fertilizer']
    category_dict['commodity'] = ['grain','wheat','barley']
    agronomy_tweet = set()
    commodity_tweet = set()
    def fetch_tweet(tweets):
    for items in tweets:
        raw_tweet = items.get('tweet_text').encode('utf 8').split()
        items_tweet = set(raw_tweet)
        if set(category_dict['agronomy']) & items_tweet:
            agronomy_tweet.add(items.get('tweet_text'))
        if set(category_dict['commodity']) & items_tweet:
            commodity_tweet.add(items.get('tweet_text')
```

Comment: What does the category_dict look like? Are the values lists? What is the application? Are you trying to optimize too early? Where is your bottleneck and what is the objective?

Comment: I have loads of tweets and want to categorize tweets in depending on keywords listed in tweet .. one my category 'agronomy' has keywords like " fertilizers" ,"soil"  and other category "general new" contains keywords like "agriculture"...   now I will pass tweets if tweet has keyword of that category .. I need to show tweet under particular category

Comment: category_dict = {}
    category_dict['agronomy']  = ['cropping','fertilizer']
    category_dict['commodity'] = ['grain','wheat','barley']
    agronomy_tweet = set()
    commodity_tweet = set()
    def fetch_tweet(tweets):
    for items in tweets:
        raw_tweet = items.get('tweet_text').encode('utf 8').split()
        items_tweet = set(raw_tweet)
        if set(category_dict['agronomy']) & items_tweet:
            agronomy_tweet.add(items.get('tweet_text'))
        if set(category_dict['commodity']) & items_tweet:
            commodity_tweet.add(items.get('tweet_text')